CLion, Goland can't create dev containers anymore: "fromJson(...) must not be null" when it downloads its own software
Attempting to build dev container with CLion 2024.1.2 and .3, it worked during few days
But now, I'm unable to create a dev container anymore.

I've tried every repair operation of the IDE
I've deleted .idea folder for a try
I've issued docker system prune, docker-compose down --remove-orphans
I even deleted /home/dev/cache/JetbrainsDist caches...

But it ends:
fromJson(...) must not be null at the moment the host attempt to download tools (it seems)

Building dev container
with these entries in idea.log:
2024-06-10 14:26:27,203 [  62079]   WARN - #c.i.c.d.g.u.s.b.DevcontainerBuildingStagePanel - fromJson(...) must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: fromJson(...) must not be null
    at com.intellij.remoteDev.util.ProductInfo$Companion.fromJson(ProductInfo.kt:27)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.util.IdeInfo.toInstalledIde(WorkerResponses.kt:15)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.GoHighLevelHostAccessor.parseInstalledIdeOutput(GoHighLevelHostAccessor.kt:414)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.GoHighLevelHostAccessor.getInstalledIDEs(GoHighLevelHostAccessor.kt:409)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.GoHighLevelHostAccessor$getInstalledIDEs$1.invokeSuspend(GoHighLevelHostAccessor.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
2024-06-10 14:26:30,151 [  65027]   INFO - #c.i.u.g.s.GistStorageImpl - Cleaning old huge-gists dirs from [/home/dev/.cache/JetBrains/CLion2024.1/caches/huge-gists] ...
2024-06-10 14:26:30,153 [  65029]   INFO - #c.i.u.g.s.GistStorageImpl - Cleaning old huge-gists dirs finished
2024-06-10 14:26:39,486 [  74362]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-06-10 14:26:39,486 [  74362]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity 

Both CLion and Goland are now togheter unable to build dev containers.
I don't know what to do.

Hi! Is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-156525 your bug report? If so, let's continue there; I need some details from you to better understand the possible reasons for this problem.
